# mysqli_num_rows returns false but data is added to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm getting an error

Here's the code:

```
<?php

//db connection

$dbserv="localhost:3306";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="firepower";
$dbname="account_data";
$db_connect=new mysqli($dbserv, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($db_connect->connect_errno){
    die("Error trying to connect to database");
}

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['current_page'])){
  $prev_page=$_SESSION['current_page'];
  $_SESSION['current_page'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
else{
  $prev_page='';
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
  header('location:'.'index.php?_rdr');
  die();
}

$limit=$_SESSION['limit'];
$index=1;
$first=true;
$products_ordered='';

while($index<=$limit){
  if(isset($_POST[$index]) && $first==true){
    $products_ordered.=$_POST[$index].' x Pizza '.$_SESSION['prod_name'][$index];
    $first=false;
  }
  else if(isset($_POST[$index]) && $first==false){
    $products_ordered.=', '.$_POST[$index].' x Pizza '.$_SESSION['prod_name'][$index];
  }
  $index++;
}

//insert order into db

$user_email=$_SESSION['email'];
$total_price=$_SESSION['order_price'];

$query="INSERT INTO orders (email, products_ordered, total_price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$sql_sec=$db_connect->prepare($query);
$sql_sec->bind_param("ssi", $user_email, $products_ordered, $total_price);
$sql_sec->execute();
$result=$sql_sec->get_result();


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
  exit("Order added successfully!");
}
else{
  exit("Error connecting to database!");
}

?>
```

It's so strange because data is added correctly to my database and the other times I used the same code (for user registration) it worked with no problems... I checked everything and I can't find the problem.

```
$query="INSERT INTO orders (email, products_ordered, total_price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$sql_sec=$db_connect->prepare($query);
$sql_sec->bind_param("ssi", $user_email, $products_ordered, $total_price);
$sql_sec->execute();
$result=$sql_sec->get_result();


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
  exit("Order added successfully!");
}
else{
  exit("Error connecting to database!");
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> **Warning**: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dream Pizza\add_order.php on line 58
>   Error connecting to database!

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to get a better error message. -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You need to remove the port from `$dbserv="localhost:3306";` From the PHP docs "`mysqli::__construct ([ string $host`  parameter  "`host ..."

    Can be either a host name or an IP address.`"   Doesn't look like the manual say it's posssible to add the port to the host string. -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php besides there is a seperated port parameter within the mysqi contructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `get_result()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, **or FALSE for other DML queries** or on failure.

You're executing an `INSERT` query, so `get_result()` will return `false`.

Instead, you should be using the `mysqli_stmt_*` functions (or just access the properties directly) to obtain information about the query's result from your `$sql_sec` statement directly:

```
if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($sql_sec)){
// or:
if($sql_sec->affected_rows) {
```

Note that you need to check the **`affected_rows`** property, not the **`num_rows`** property. The reason is that `num_rows` returns the number of rows in the *result set*. You're not selecting a result set, you're inserting a new set of data. That means you're actually interested in the number of rows that was inserted, which is stored in the `affected_rows` property.